# How to configure custom authentication proxy with kubernetes dashboard ui in EKS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy the Kube dashboard ui in our EKS cluster but all the requests must be authenticated via a custom identity provider.

So I have created an authentication proxy container in .NET which will run as a sidecar with the Kube dashboard.

Now configured the ALB path to route the request of https://www.cosco.com/dashboard to the Authentication container once authentication is done I am trying to redirect the call to https://localhost:9090 where my dashboard is running without authentication but for obvious reasons, the browser Said connection refused localhost:9090 does not exist.

How do I solve this issue? The intention here is that as Kube dashboard ui is without any authentication, all the requests must go through the authentication controller and dashboard ui is not directly accessible outside of the cluster directly.